# Start the second window of Chrome maximized

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

First new window is opened maximized. If it's minimized, the second new window won't be maximized.

I changed the shortcut to maximized, and it did nothing.

Win10.

---

I'll add that if the last opened window is:

- minimized, then the next one will not open maximized (but in normal mode);
- maximized, then the next one will open maximized.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome stores away its window display setting when it is closed, not while
it is being used.

To have the following Chrome windows opened as maximized, you should
close Chrome after maximizing it. All following Chrome windows
will then open as maximized.

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with saved settings. If I close all windows--even while maximized--the same behavior for opening the second window will be as I described.

Comment: I may not be doing the same operation as you. How are you opening the second Chrome?

Comment: From a link on the desktop. Similarly, when I run the .exe from cmd. Same behavior on my work pc.

Comment: Strange, I do the same, but on my computer Chrome remembers the previous position and size of its window. Let me know if there is something different on your computer, on mine I just used the official installation of Chrome.